# Why the LTRIM function is not returning the expected result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying the get the location name after the title from a column. An example of a position name is 'Manager - Miami'. I am trying the following,

```
 SELECT UPPER(LTRIM('Manager - Miami', 'Manager - ')) FROM DUAL
```

I am expecting the output to be `MIAMI`, but it's returning only `IAMI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(L)TRIM? Why would you use it to return "Miami"? I'd go with SUBSTR + INSTR, such as in this example (CTE is just so that I wouldn't have to repeat the string several times).

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Manager - Miami' from dual)
  3  select trim(substr(col, instr(col, '-') + 1)) result
  4  from test;

RESUL
-----
Miami

SQL>
```

Besides, what is `District Manager -` 's purpose? Do you want to select location from that too? There's none, so - NULL will be returned:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'District Manager - ' from dual)
  3  select trim(substr(col, instr(col, '-') + 1)) result
  4  from test;

R
-


SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks. District Manager was written by mistake, it should be only 'Manager'. I've edited the question. This will work for my case.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, the second argument to `LTRIM()` is a list of characters.  By default, these are case-sensitive.

So, `'m'` is the first character in `''Manager - Miami'` that is not in `'District Manager - '`, so everything before it is removed.

I can speculate that you actually want some sort of `regexp_substr()` or `regexp_replace()`, but you don't really specify the logic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It was removing all the characters from the 'set'. A combination of SUBSTR and INSTR worked perfectly.

Comment: @Priom . . . If you had explained what you wanted to accomplish, I probably would have answered that as well.

Answer (score 2):

And here's the regex_substr version that will select what is after the last dash/space at the end of the string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Manager - Miami', '- (.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) FROM DUAL;
```